# Couldn't understand this SWIFT Fucntion

Tags: swift, function

Hope you are doing well. Would anyone please explain this code to me? I am still not getting how we got 120 here. When the parameters were passed to the function, where was it saved? How did it determine max and min before calculating?

Would be really appreciated if anyone could explain it for me please..

[image: Function]

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: It goes through each element (`for score in scores`) and adds them up (`sum += score`). Where's the confusion here? It doesn't determine max before calculating, it just sets the first entry to be the initial max, then adjusts as it goes through.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting 120 because you're asking the tuple for the `sum` value twice. The tuple passed back is `(min: Int, max: Int, sum: Int)`.  In this case, `sum` is also index number 2 (`min` is index zero, `max` is index one). So in this case `statistics.sum == statistics.2`

If you want to access `min` or `max` you can access them using `statistics.min` or `statistics.max` respectively.  You can also use `statistics.0` or `statistics.1` if you prefer (I recommend using the labels though).

Final thought: I would change your initial assignment of `max` and `min` inside the function to read as follows:

```
guard var max = scores.first, var min = scores.first else {
   return (0, 0, 0)
}
```

This will protect against the user accidentally passing an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You could have also set min and max to `0` ,not to `scores[0]`.
This func is very simple, I think you should read somewhere `How functions are working`.
For loop is used to go through every element, in your case every element in array `scores`. In every iteration, variable `sum` is increased by current element in array. So: 
At the beginning of the function : `sum = 0`
 1. iteration: `sum = 0 + 5` 
 2. iteration: `sum = 5 + 3` 
 3. iteration: `sum = 8 + 100` 
 4. iteration: `sum = 108 + 3` 
 5. iteration: `sum = 111 + 9` 
For loop ends. Sum = `120`.

Score in Scores means like every single element in score. So name `Score` can be whatever you want to name it. You could have also name it `element` , `x`, `a` or whatever you like.

Comment: No, you can't set `min` and `max` to `0`.  If the input array was `[3, 5]`, then it would return `0` as the `min`.  If the input array was `[-1, -2]`, it would return `0` as the `max`.  Both of those are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The function returns a tuple of type `(min: Int, max: Int, sum: Int)`.
`max` and `min` are not determined before being calculated. When they're first assigned at the top of the function, they just contain the first element of the passed in `scores` array. But by the time the loop below finishes, they indeed have the correct minimum and maximum values. Those values are then returned in a tuple matching the return type.